# react router render page blank

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, render

I get a blank page with my render. I checked in the other similar questions to find the solution but I still get this blank page.
THank you for your help!

This is my code:

App.js

```js
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Events from './components/Events/Events';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <h1>Marine Mammals</h1>
      <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/Events' element={<Events/>}>
          <Events/>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    
      </BrowserRouter>

    </div>
  );
}



export default App;
```

Events.js

```js
import React from 'react';

export default function Events(){
  return<h2>Events</h2>;
}
```

Comment: Is your URL you're testing `/Events`? Does `Events` render anything? Please include a [mre].

Comment: thanks. I would like to see Events displayed

Comment: In the screenshot that you posted as an answer - you are not at the correct URL.

Comment: Try the correct URL - http://localhost:3000/Events

Comment: This sounds like a missing fundamental in your understanding of react router. I would suggest reading through their docs and maybe a tutorial to solidify these basics

Comment: yes you are right! I am going to study more it. thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to look at your react-router-dom version.

In V5 you use  tags between the component that should appear in the route(nested). In version 6 you can use the element within the tag.

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#relative-routes-and-links